# What's the order to start up hdp services manually?

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I face some problems to launch hortonworks services through Ambari by starting all services, So I decide to start those services manually and I'm not sure if there is a order I should respect when starting those services. I've installed almost all sevices that we could find on hortonworks data platform.

Answer (score 2):

To start hortonworks data platform services manually through Ambari, there is a order to respect, the following [link](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_reference/content/starting_hdp_services.html) displays the list of the most frequent services we can use on HDP :

```
Ranger
Knox
ZooKeeper
HDFS
YARN
HBase
Hive Metastore
HiveServer2
WebHCat
Oozie
Hue
Storm
Kafka
Atlas
```

Comment: Hmm. Spark is missing from that list

Comment: is it okey to start spark at the end ?

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, Ambari starts services by following the [Role command order](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Role+Command+Order) definition files. These files may be defined per-service, or once for the entire stack.

So you may take a look at `role_command_order.json` files in your stack. For example, [here](https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/src/main/resources/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/role_command_order.json) is the `role_command_order.json` file for HDP-2.0.6 stack.

If the role_command_order.json file is missing, then it is inherited from some other stack. For example the `<extends>` tag [here](https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/src/main/resources/stacks/HDP/2.6/metainfo.xml) means that HDP-2.6 stack extends HDP-2.5 stack. Basically, all HDP-2.x stacks inherit 
the `role_command_order.json` file for HDP-2.0.6 stack.